# Python process never returns, have to interrupt and finally get a in _wait_for_tstate_lock message

Tags: python, multiprocessing, locking

I'm trying to help a colleague speeding up a jupiter notebook with some multiprocessing. I'm not good at this :-/

Something is wrong, the program never returns and I can't understand why.
I have to stop execution and then I can see in the stack that a  in _wait_for_tstate_lock is occuring.

According to my program outputs, it seems that the process is done... "None" item is detected in the queue and the while loop should end.

For information, the job is about importing xlsx files, cleaning them with panda, and concatenate them in a single dataframe. (1 file for testing purpose, approx 80Mb on the drive)

Worked like a charm when no multiprocessing was involved.

Outputs

```
Journal_Appels_2019_01.xlsx démarré par Process-86
Journal_Appels_2019_01.xlsx importé en 113.18582201004028 secondes
Fin du processus Process-86
```

Stack ater interrupting (keyboard interupt)

```
File "/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 191, in _finalize_join
    thread.join()
  File "/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1056, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
  File "/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1072, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Code

```py
from multiprocessing import Lock, Process, Queue, current_process
import time


def do_job(tasks_to_accomplish, tasks_that_are_done):
    while True:
            task = tasks_to_accomplish.get_nowait()
            if (task is None):
                print('Fin du processus ' + current_process().name)
                break

            print(task + ' démarré par ' + current_process().name)
            starttime = time.time()
            tasks_that_are_done.put(import_journal(task))
            print(task + ' importé en {} secondes'.format(time.time() - starttime))


# setting up
number_of_processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
tasks_to_accomplish = Queue()
tasks_that_are_done = Queue()
processes = []

# read files list in a directory, get only the first one fort testing purpose
for element in os.listdir(path)[:1]:
    tasks_to_accomplish.put(element)

# end of process signal
for element in os.listdir(path)[:number_of_processes]:
    tasks_to_accomplish.put(None)

# creating processes
for w in range(1):
    p = Process(target=do_job, args=(tasks_to_accomplish, tasks_that_are_done))
    processes.append(p)
    p.start()

# completing process
for p in processes:
    p.join()

# concat the outputs
print('Concaténation')
while not tasks_that_are_done.empty():
    comptage_jrdemiheureGT_tot = pd.concat([comptage_jrdemiheureGT_tot,tasks_that_are_done.get()],axis=0,sort=True)
print("terminé")
```